# Recurse over a list of querysets of unknown depth

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, generator

I have a requirement where I need to be able to create multiple nodes in an org-chart type situation.  The requirements call for a "child" node being able to have multiple parents, so existing solutions like `mptt` or `treebeard` are out unfortunately.

The requirements also state that I should be to access a Node at any level and be able to do business stuff based on its children.

Here is my attempt:

```
class Division(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
    )
    children_set = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='organisations.Division',
        related_name='parent_set',
    )

    def _flatten_children(self, el):
        for item in el.children_set.all():
            if bool(item.children_set.count()):
                yield from self._flatten_children(item)
            else:
                yield item

    def all_children(self):
        return list(self._flatten_children(self))

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children_set.add(child)
```

When calling this, I only seem to be getting the queryset of the "last" child.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# test setup
instance = DivisionFactory()
child1 = DivisionFactory()
child2 = DivisionFactory()
child3 = DivisionFactory()
child4 = DivisionFactory()

instance.add_child(child1)
child1.add_child(child2)
child2.add_child(child3)
child2.add_child(child4)
```

Output:

```
In [19]: instance.all_children()
Out[19]: [<Division: Officia dolores illo.>, <Division: Vitae sapiente numquam.>]
```

Notice how only the two child nodes for `child2` have been returned, and both `child1` and `child2` have not been included in the returned list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code yield only the items without child. You need yield them all (including self)

```
def _flatten_children(self, el):
    for item in el.children_set.all():
        if bool(item.children_set.count()):
            yield from self._flatten_children(item)
        yield item  # <----  # children first
```

or

```
def _flatten_children(self, el):
    for item in el.children_set.all():
        yield item  # <----  # parents first
        if bool(item.children_set.count()):
            yield from self._flatten_children(item)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, so obvious.  Remember kids, don't write this stuff at 4am.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe it was obvious to me because it was 8am here. ;)